# Unable to unzip gzipped data stored in redis in nodejs. "Z_DATA_ERROR"

Tags: node.js, node-redis

I encoded the a JSON object using msgpack5 and used zlib.gzip to compress and  store it in node-redis list.

Here is the code :

```
zlib.gzip(msgpack.encode(data), function(err, compressedData) {
  if (err) {
    return callback(err);
  }
  var suffix = "fetch";
  var listHead =  userId + ":" + suffix;
  return redis.lpush(listHead, compressedData, callback);
});
```

This works totally fine. I use :

```
lrange(listHead, 0, -1, function(err, values)
```

to fetch the list.

But the following code doesn't work :

```
  compressedData = new Buffer(compressedData);   
  zlib.gunzip(compressedData, function(err, unzippedObj) {
      if (err) {
        return callback(err);
      }
    return callback(null, msgpack.decode(unzippedObj));
  });
```

where `CompressedData` is each value of a list in redis

This code produces :

```
 {"errno":-3,"code":"Z_DATA_ERROR"}
```

When I log compressed Data before and after putting in redis list, It outputs the same buffer. Please help.

Comment: I'm not sure about `node-redis` but in `ioredis` you have to use special method to get Buffer, like `redis.getBuffer()`

Comment: I am converting the fetched string to buffer and then trying to decompress. This ain't working.

Comment: is there any solutions?